# How do I center the part title at KOMA-script?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, parts

I want to centering the title of the part, and it's not working:

```
\renewcommand*\raggedpart{\centering}
\setkomafont{part}{\itshape\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{part~ :\thepart~~}
```

I also tried without the * (at the first line):

```
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\setkomafont{part}{\itshape\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{part~ :\thepart~~}
```

both doesn't work....
So, how can I center the title?

Edit:
I also try this: `\let\raggedpart\centering` but it's still doesn't work...

Here is the file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\newcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\let\raggedpart\centering
\setkomafont{part}{\itshape\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{Part~ :\thepart~~}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\part{PART ONE}

Hello!
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a MWE that shows your issue. I can not reproduce it neither with `scrartcl` nor with `scrreprt` or `scrbook`. Using `scrreprt` or `scrbook` the part title is centred by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\raggedpart` is redefined in `scrartcl-xetex-bidi.def` by

```
\def\raggedpart{\if@RTL\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi}
```

So you have to redefine `\raggedpart` after `\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}` or to use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\centering}}
```