# How to place the parts on the same page of the next chapter? (scrbook)

Tags: koma-script, chapters, parts

Is there any way to place the name of the parts on the same page of the next chapter? I have tried to do this, to notice its effect I uncomment the commented lines, and you can see that the formatting of the chapter number and name is lost. Is there any way or trick to avoid this? Thank you in advance for any help. My minimal working example is shown below:

```
\documentclass[
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%** Decompose to appreciate the effect and in case it generates an error, compile twice.
%\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%beforeskip=\dimexpr-3.3\baselineskip-\parskip\relax,
%afterskip=\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
%style=chapter% no part page
%]{part}
%\renewcommand\partformat{\partname\ \thepart\autodot\enskip}

%\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
%beforeskip=-1sp,
%afterskip=1.725\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip,
%style=section,% no page break before \firstchapterinpart
%level=\chapternumdepth,
%indent=0pt,
%tocindent=0pt,
%tocnumwidth=1.5em,
%font=\usekomafont{chapter},
%tocstyle=chapter,
%tocnumwidth=1.5em
%]{firstchapterinpart}

%\renewcommand\partformat{\partname\ \thepart\autodot\enskip}

%\makeatletter
%\let\c@firstchapterinpart\c@chapter% use the same counter for both chapter and firstchapterinpart
%\def\cl@firstchapterinpart{\cl@chapter}% use the same reset list as chapter
%\makeatother
%%%**

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents    
    
    
\part{Name of The First Part..}
%\firstchapterinpart{Name of the First Chapter}
\chapter{Name of the First Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here  
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
    
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
    
\chapter{Another chapter from part one}
    
\minitoc
\section{Section ??? }
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted }
Text
\subsubsection{Section 1.1}
Testing stuff out
\part{Name of The Second Part..}
%\firstchapterinpart{Name of the first chapter of part 2}
\chapter{Name of the first chapter of part 2}   
\minitoc
\section{Section 1.1 why does it appear 3. if this belongs to chapter two?}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{appreciate this}
\chapter{Other Chapter name}
\minitoc
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{jjj}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

As you may notice, English is not my native language. Apologies in advance, if it's bad, poor and broken, a thousand apologies :)

Comment: This solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419404/4736 ?

Comment: I do not see a difference in the chapter format. But the format of the part heading changes and \minitoc after \firstchapterinpart{...} is missing. If that is your problem please edit your question.

Comment: Dear, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419404/4736, I had already exhausted this alternative before, as you can see in the similarity of the code, in fact that's where I started with the solution to my problem, but I didn't get my goal. On the other hand, adding \minitoc after \firstchapterinpart{...}, does not generate any solution, I am not sure if you have tried my code to see the problem, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not reproduce the lose of the chapter number and name. But the format of the part heading changes and the local table of contents in the first chapter of a part is lost.

Here is a suggestion using package `etoc` instead `minitoc`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{etoc}
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{% etoc style for locals TOC 
  \etocsettocstyle
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\textbf{\contentsname}\\[-.7\baselineskip]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.3\baselineskip}
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}% 
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  afterskip=\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  style=chapter% no part page
]{part}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\partformat}{}{\partname\ \thepart\autodot\enskip}
\NewCommandCopy{\originalchapterlinesformat}{\chapterlinesformat}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterlinesformat}{mmm}{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{part}
    {\centering#2\par\vskip.5\baselineskip#3}% format of part headings
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}% original definition for other levels using style=chapter
}
%
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter,
]{chapter}{firstchapterinpart}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=1.725\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip,
style=section,% no page break before \firstchapterinpart
level=\chapternumdepth,
indent=0pt,
font=\usekomafont{chapter}
]{firstchapterinpart}
\etocsetlevel{firstchapterinpart}{\chapternumdepth}

\makeatletter
\let\c@firstchapterinpart\c@chapter% use the same counter for both chapter and firstchapterinpart
\def\cl@firstchapterinpart{\cl@chapter}% use the same reset list as chapter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Name of The First Part..}
\firstchapterinpart{Name of the First Chapter}
%\chapter{Name of the First Chapter}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here  
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\chapter{Another chapter from part one}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section ??? }
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted }
Text
\subsubsection{Section 1.1}
Testing stuff out

\part{Name of The Second Part..}
\firstchapterinpart{Name of the first chapter of part 2}
%\chapter{Name of the first chapter of part 2}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1 why does it appear 3. if this belongs to chapter two?}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{appreciate this}
\chapter{Other Chapter name}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{jjj}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Additional remark** because of a comment below:
If part headings should not have a prefix line, remove  the redefinition of `\chapterlinesformat` in the code above:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{etoc}
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{% etoc style for locals TOC 
  \etocsettocstyle
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\textbf{\contentsname}\\[-.7\baselineskip]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.3\baselineskip}
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}% 
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  afterskip=\dimexpr3.3\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  style=chapter% no part page
]{part}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\partformat}{}{\partname\ \thepart\autodot\enskip}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter,
]{chapter}{firstchapterinpart}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=1.725\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip,
style=section,% no page break before \firstchapterinpart
level=\chapternumdepth,
indent=0pt,
font=\usekomafont{chapter}
]{firstchapterinpart}
\etocsetlevel{firstchapterinpart}{\chapternumdepth}

\makeatletter
\let\c@firstchapterinpart\c@chapter% use the same counter for both chapter and firstchapterinpart
\def\cl@firstchapterinpart{\cl@chapter}% use the same reset list as chapter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Name of The First Part..}
\firstchapterinpart{Name of the First Chapter}
%\chapter{Name of the First Chapter}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here  
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\chapter{Another chapter from part one}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section ??? }
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted }
Text
\subsubsection{Section 1.1}
Testing stuff out

\part{Name of The Second Part..}
\firstchapterinpart{Name of the first chapter of part 2}
%\chapter{Name of the first chapter of part 2}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1 why does it appear 3. if this belongs to chapter two?}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{appreciate this}
\chapter{Other Chapter name}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1.1}
Text goes here
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out
\section{jjj}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! it works wonderfully well and it is exactly what I was looking for, I am very interested to know how the code you have implemented works. For now I wanted to ask how to remove the blank page that is before each chapter the chapter? I thank you very much for having taken the trouble to solve my concern, best regards and have a happy day :).

Comment: @FredyDíaz Then accept esdd's answer and you might even consider to upvote it!

Comment: @FredyDíaz If chapters should start on even and odd pages (without empty pages) add option `open=any` to the class: `\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}`.

Comment: Dear Once again thank you for clarifying my doubt, your answers have been very helpful.  Dear @Dosis de Keks Thank you too,  I am really new to the group, I was looking for a way to cast a vote to the good response obtained, I appreciate if you can tell me how to do it, cordial greetings.

Comment: @FredyDíaz There are symbols left of an answer. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853

Comment: Dear @esdd I wanted to ask you an extra question, is it possible to have the Part I label and the text on the same line, i.e. something like: "Part I Name of The First Part...".
According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455238/fixing-part-layout-using-patchcmd my attempt was to redefine the KOMA-Script command \partheadmidvskip to remove the line break between the part number and the text of the part, but I did not succeed, I appreciate for any help :)...

Comment: @FredyDíaz Remove the redefinition of `\chapterlinesformat`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Dear @esdd Again I offer you immense thanks for your thoughtful collaboration, it has been very useful your help for me... the only doubt that has arisen for me is how to do that-Part I Name of the first part-what centering. I tried to solve with the exposed here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458162/how-do-i-center-the-part-title-at-koma-script), but I could not achieve it, thank you for your collaboration and apologize for being so insistent.. :)

Comment: Then `\chapterlinesformat` must be redefined again. But the redefinition depends on the desired result of longer part headings. Should the part heading get a hanging label if the part heading needs more than one line? Maybe you have to ask a new question.